# No route found for "GET /"

Tags: php, symfony

I'm having problems to getting my site to work.

I already I have another site running and I have this problem even though the configuration are the same.

This is my general routing.yml

```
ceroacien_user:
    resource: "@CeroacienUserBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /users

ceroacien_security:
    resource: "@CeroacienSecurityBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /

ceroacien_security_logout:
    resource: "@CeroacienSecurityBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /logout
```

And this is my bundle routing.yml

```
security_homepage:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: CeroacienSecurityBundle:Access:login }

login:
    pattern:  /index
    defaults: { _controller: CeroacienSecurityBundle:Access:login }

login_check:
    pattern:    /login_check
    defaults:   { _controller: CeroacienSecurityBundle:Access:loginCheck }

logout:
    pattern:    /logout
    defaults:   { _controller: CeroacienSecurityBundle:Access:logout }
```

The path to my security budle is "ceroacien/src/Ceroacien/Bundle/SecurityBundle".

I work with Symfony since a few months ago but in this particular case I really don't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Have you ever tried the clean the cache ? (sry if it's obvious but lot of problems come from here). Even in dev mode.

Comment: In fact I tried cleaning both caches (dev and prod) but that doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try and remove the prefix for `ceroacien_security`

```
ceroacien_security:
    resource: "@CeroacienSecurityBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
```